# Self referencing model with Required annotation on some properties in ASP.Net MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, required, self-reference

I have this selfreferencing Model:

```
public class AddressDataViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public String Country {get; set;}

    public String Town {get; set;}

    public AddressDataViewModel AdditionalAddress {get; set;}
}
```

Problem is that the Required attribute is also applicated to the Country property of self referenced object AdditionalAddress and so on.
Is there some easy way to suppress this? I only want Required validation to first of the hierarchy.

Thanks.

Comment: Cause I have there many properties and I don't want to add the same properties more times only with some additional prefix (for example AdditionalTown, AdditionalCountry...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this with a base and derived class:

```
public abstract class AddressDataViewModel
{

    public virtual String Country {get; set;}

    public String Town {get; set;}

}

public class PrimaryAddressDataViewModel : AddressDataViewModel
{

    [Required]
    public Overrides String Country {get; set;}

}

public class AdditionalAddressDataViewModel : AddressDataViewModel
{
}

public class AddressesDataViewModel
{
     public PrimaryAddressDataViewModel PrimaryAddress {get;set;}
     IEnumerable<AdditionalAddressDataViewModel> AdditionalAddresses {get;set;}
}
```